# Lxml cssselect wildcard

Tags: html, xpath, screen-scraping, lxml

How do I get all the wildcard elements using cssselect?

For example:

```
content = """
<table>
<tr id='Awesome1234'><a href="link1"></a></tr>
<tr id='Awesome5678'><a href="link2"></a></tr>
</table>
"""
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
links = lxml.cssselection('tr.Awesome* a')
for link in links:
    print link.get('href')
```

I want it to output:

```
 link1
 link2
```

Is this possible with cssselect?  If not, how can I get this? (xpath?)

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and short, one-liner XPath solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use the following XPath expression** (no css is required):

```
tr[starts-with(@id, 'Awesome')]
```

This XPath expression selects all `tr` children of the context node that have an `id` attribute, whose string value starts with the string 'Awsome'.

Comment: Using parens inside the matching string like that gives me SelectorSyntaxError: Operator expected, got <DELIM '(' at 15>\

Comment: @Amalgovinus, This means that you have fed the XPath expression to CSS somehow. An XPath expression must be processed by an XPath engine -- in this example most probably by the one available in JavaScript. This question is tagged "xpath" -- hence the XPath solution :) And do note that the OP is asking (at the end of the question) for an XPath solution.

Comment: Yep, I was passing XPath junk to the the css func --had it backwards. thanks

Answer (score 4):

`^=` comparison operator seems for you:

```
tr[id^=Awesome] a
```